# Wordpress on Openshift, very slow to respond

Tags: wordpress, openshift, haproxy

I've just moved my Wordpress website on OpenShift PAAS ecosystem, on a scalable PHP cartridge. But I immediately noticed the website is really slow to respond - around 3000/4000 milliseconds. BUT, when it starts to respond, the page loading/rendering is absolutely fast.

here's the url: http://gabrielebaldassarre.com

just to give you a comparison, this static website is hosted on the same AWS Region: http://extras.gabrielebaldassarre.com/tos5-4

For that reason, I pointed this bottleneck to the nameservers I use (from Cloudflare, because of naked CNAME needs), but using a online tester, they seems ok.

I wouldn't say that my Wordpress is a vanilla config, but it's not a mammoth, after all. And loading time after response starting is ok.

I'm wondering if there is something wrong with HAProxy, or my OpenShift configuration, but I don't know how to check or what to do about.

any idea?

Comment: Have you logged a call with OpenShift?

Comment: well, ehm, no. I don't know how to do that, to be honest..i'm definitively new on OpenShift and PAAS in general

Comment: You just need to create a new case here: https://access.redhat.com/support/cases/new/

Comment: is it for the free users, too?

Comment: I am not sure, perhaps not. No harm in trying?

Comment: done; it's for enterprise red hat linux only :(

Comment: access.redhat.com is for paid users only.

Comment: I'm run into too. The first request is so slow but the fallowing requests are fast.

Answer (score 6):

Openshift suspends and serializes apps without much activity after a given period, and the first time they 'wake' they deserialize and this takes time.

Answer (score 0):

Since your a free user, I'm assuming that your application is deployed on small gears. Depending on the size of your application, that may not be enough. Try signing up for the bronze plan and see if your application performance improves on a medium or large gear.

Comment: I thought about that, but...it's wordpress! it's nothing you would need a medium gear, usually. And before buy something, I would like to be sure it's not a misconfiguration issue

Comment: Understood, it was just a suggestion. To get a look at what resources your application is consuming try sshing into your gear with `rhc ssh <appname>` and executing the following: 

`top` and
`for i in $(oo-cgroup-read all);do echo “oo-cgroup-read $i” && oo-cgroup-read $i; done`

Then append your question with the output from above.