# Openshift haproxy - web-service hibernated

Tags: openshift, load-balancing, haproxy

I'm using small webapp which is hosted on `openshift` and that app is actually a web-serviсe. Sinse my app is `scalable` it is maintained by `haproxy` load baloancer. But I noticed that my app was hibernated after some period of time.

Why does it happen? 
Is haproxy able to maintaine web-service application?

---

*as it turned out there were just terminology problems as scalable does not mean that it will not idling. thus the issue has been resolved.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ping Service to stop OpenShift Application from IDLE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379410/ping-service-to-stop-openshift-application-from-idle)

Comment: From what I understand, regardless if you say it is "scalable", that doesn't mean you won't become idle with some period of inactivity.

Comment: Haproxy is a load balancer, you may benefit by googling "haproxy heartbeat"

Comment: @xkcd149 you were right that scalable and idle are independent. so the best option is using a tool to ping the resource to stop the application from idling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684012/wordpress-on-openshift-very-slow-to-respond?rq=1) "Openshift suspends and serializes apps without much activity after a given period, and the first time they 'wake' they deserialize and this takes time."